# Convert numpy, list or float to string in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a python function to append data to text file, as shown in the following,

The problem is the variable, `var`, could be a 1D numpy array, a 1D list, or just a float number, I know how to convert `numpy.array`/`list`/`float` to string separately (meaning given the type), but is there a method to convert `var` to string without knowing its type?

```
def append_txt(filename, var):
    my_str = _____    # convert var to string
    with open(filename,'a') as f:
        f.write(my_str + '\n')
```

Edit 1: Thanks for the comments, sorry maybe my question was not clear enough. 
`str(var)` on numpy would give something like `[]`. For example, `var = np.ones((1,3)), str(var)` will give `[[1. 1. 1.]]`, and `[]` is unwanted,

Edit 2: Since I want to write clean numbers (meaning no `[` or `]`), it seems type checking is inevitable.

Comment: This may help http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html

Comment: How about `str(var)`?

Answer (score 6):

Type checking is not the only option to do what you want, but definitely one of the easiest:

```
import numpy as np

def to_str(var):
    if type(var) is list:
        return str(var)[1:-1] # list
    if type(var) is np.ndarray:
        try:
            return str(list(var[0]))[1:-1] # numpy 1D array
        except TypeError:
            return str(list(var))[1:-1] # numpy sequence
    return str(var) # everything else
```

**EDIT:** Another easy way, **which does not use type checking** (thanks to jtaylor for giving me that idea), is to convert everything into the same type (`np.array`) and then convert it to a string:

```
import numpy as np

def to_str(var):
    return str(list(np.reshape(np.asarray(var), (1, np.size(var)))[0]))[1:-1]
```

**Example use** (both methods give same results):

```
>>> to_str(1.) #float
'1.0'
>>> to_str([1., 1., 1.]) #list
'1.0, 1.0, 1.0'
>>> to_str(np.ones((1,3))) #np.array
'1.0, 1.0, 1.0'
```

Comment: np.savetxt can also be used to save numpy arrays in a readable way, array.tolist() creates a nested list for you

Comment: @jtaylor That's not a bad idea. However, for that to work, you would have to convert all types into a `np.array`. And when that is done, you might as well just convert it to string yourself. I edited my answer to include that method.

Answer (score 4):

`str` is able to convert any type into string. It can be numpy.array / list / float

```
# using numpy array
new_array = numpy.array([1,2,3])
str(new_array)
>> '[1 2 3]'

# using list
new_list = [1, 2, 3]
str(new_list)
>> '[1, 2, 3]'

# using float
new_float = 1.1
str(new_float)
>> '1.1'
```

Comment: When it's some string with weird encoding, str() can raise some weird error.

Comment: Can you list the string and the error that was raised?

Comment: I was thinking about unicode string, str(u"\u03A9") raises an UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: The unicodeEncodeError doesn't occur in Python3. If you are using Python 2, you can use str(var).encode('utf-8')

Comment: Good to know this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what is the type of var you can check type using

```
from collections import Iterable
if isinstance(var,Iteratable):
    mystring=''.join(map(str,var))
else:
    mystring=str(var)
```

Comment: this would work, btw, there is a typo: if isinstance(var,Iterable):

Comment: str(numpy array) will not print the full array if its large, you have to change the print options, convert to list or use savetxt to get all data in text form

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html)

It's the opposite of the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

Here's what `eval` does:

```
eval('[1,3]')
# [1, 3]
```

Here's what `repr` does:

```
repr('example')
# "'example'"
repr(0.1)
# '0.1'
repr([1,2])
# '[1,2]'
```

Comment: However, `repr(np.ones((1,3)))` will give `'array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])'`. Good idea, though!