# How do you convert a numpy.float64 to Python native string type for writing to a file with write()?

Tags: python, string, numpy

How do you convert a numpy.float64 to Python native string type for writing to a file with write()?

Comment: use `str(your_float)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert numpy, list or float to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914735/convert-numpy-list-or-float-to-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `str()`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

print(type(x))

print(type(str(x)))
```

Yields:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly write the array values into a file with [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

`np.savetxt(filename,myarray)`